# Mapping stored procedure result set to entity/POJO using Spring JPA with SQL Server - SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, repository

I am using Spring JPA to execute a stored procedure in my application. The stored procedure takes two parameters and returns a result set. I have a repository interface called CarRepository that extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer>. In the repository, I have a custom method getAllCars annotated with @Procedure to invoke the stored procedure.

Here is the updated code snippet for the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {
    @Procedure(name = "Car.GetUsersByCity")
    Object[] getAllCars(@Param("cityName") String city, @Param("countryName") String country);
}
```

The Car entity class is already defined.

When I invoke the getAllCars method, I encounter the following exception:

```
SOL Error: 102, SQLState: S0001
2023-05-30 12:17:52.817 ERROR 1508 _.- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine. jdbc. spi.SqlExceptionHelper
:Incorrect syntax near .
2023-05-30 12:17:52.860 ERROR 1508--- (nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.c.[.(.(/].(dispatcherServlet]
: Servlet.service () for
servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [J threw exception [Request processing failed: nested exception 13 org.springframework.dao. InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet: SQL (n/a]: nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near
at com.microsoft.sqlserver. jdbc. SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError (SQLServerException. java:216)
```

I have verified that the stored procedure GetUsersByCity is correctly defined in my SQL Server database with the appropriate parameter names and data types. However, I am unable to identify the cause of the syntax error.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully map the result set from the stored procedure to the desired entity or POJO class using Spring JPA and SQL Server.

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the name of the procedure in the database is `Car.GetUsersByCity`. If that's the case, then replace your annotation with

```java
@Procedure(procedureName = "Car.GetUsersByCity")
```

From the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/Procedure.html), "name" is dedicated to the name of the procedure in the EntityManager